# Compositions of $n+2$ into summands $\geq 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to determine the generating function of the number of compositions of $n+2$ into summands which are $\geq 2$ (i.e. summands may repeat and the order of the summands is relevant)

$\mathcal A:=\{2,3,4,\dots\} \Rightarrow A(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}-1-z=\frac{z^2}{1-z}$

$\mathcal D:=\mathrm{SEQ(A)}\Rightarrow$

$$ D(z)=\frac{1}{1-A(z)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{1-z}}=\frac{1-z}{1-z-z^2}$$

Because we want the generating function of $n+2$ we have to evaluate $$\tilde D(z)=\frac{D(z)-d_0-d_1z}{z^2}$$ where $d_n:=[z^n]D(z)$

> I don't quite understand why we have $d_0=1$ and $d_1=0$. I know how to calculate $d_0$ and $d_1$ (and I get the correct solutions this way)  but I thought $d_0$ is the number of partitions of $0$ into summands $\geq 2$ and therefore $d_0$ should be $0$. Likewise $d_1$ is the number of partitions of $1$ into summands $\geq 2$ and should also be $0$ but obviously this is wrong. So what do $d_0$ and $d_1$ actually mean?

Comment: You need to divide by $z^2$ to shift the indexing $2$ places: you want $\tilde d_n=d_{n+2}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I need $[z^n]\tilde D(z)$ where $\tilde D$ is defined as above but I was wondering how I can determine $d_0$ and $d_1$ easily

Comment: **SPetrakos** has already answered the questionn for $d_0$, and it’s clear from the definition that $d_1=0$. I was just pointing out that your generating function $\tilde D(z)$ is incorrect: the denominator should be $z^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe $d_0=1$ because $0$ can be partitioned into $0$ summands and an empty set of summands can be assumed to satisfy anything (including that each summand is $\geq 2$).

Comment: Yes, I think that is indeed the reason. Thanks!